# Bash for loop stops after first iteration

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following bash code. The for loop takes values from two successive locations of an array. Then it creates a corresponding directory in a cluster. There it creates a .cpki file and runs it in the cluster. Unfortunately this code stops working after first iteration.

```
declare -a CT
CT=(2 0 -1 -2)
len=${#CT[@]}

for ((i=0;i<len;i++)); do
    a=${CT[$i]}
    b=${CT[$((i+1))]}
    input=${job_type}_${a}_${b}

    WorkDir=/scratch/$USER/${input}.${JOB_ID} #Directory in a cluster
    mkdir -p $WorkDir;
    cd $WorkDir;      #Go to cluster 
    ...
    Code that creates ${filename}.cpki file using a and b
    ...

    $MPIRUN -np $NSLOTS $CP2K -i "${filename}.cpki"> "${filename}.cpko"

done
```

Comment: Add `echo "i=$i and len=$len"` on different places.

Comment: What lines can you to delete after which the problem still occurs. I would like to see this minimal example!

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether **len** variable is changed unintentionally in the

> Code that creates ${filename}.cpki file using a and b

part of the script.